# How to relate a table to multiple other tables while still having one-to-many relationship?

Tags: django, django-models

Let's say I have the following model classes:

```
# Inspection target
class Target(models.Model):
    ...

# Issue found during the inspection
class Issue(models.Model):
    target = models.ForeignKey(Target, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='issues')
```

So, a `Target` can have multiple related `Issue`s, while an `Issue` always relates to one `Target`. Now, let's say I add a new table like this:

```
# Document that describes either a target or an issue
class Document(models.Model):
    ...
```

... and I want this both `Target`s and `Issue`s to have references to `Document`s, but a single `Document` can only be related to one object, either a `Target` or an `Issue`. Is this possible to do with Django?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your definition of `Target` and `Issue` is fine for what you want. A `Target` can have multiple `Issue`, where an `Issue` can have only relation with a single `Target`.

Now you want, `Target` and `Issue` to refer to `Document`.
For this your `models.py` will look like this.

```
class Document(models.Model):
    ...
    target = models.ForeignKey(Target, related_name='target_documents', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    issue = models.ForeignKey(Issue, related_name='issue_documents', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    ...
```

And then, the rest you have to handle in your `views.py` where you have to allow only one value either `Target` or `Issue`.

Comment: Ah, somehow overlooked this simple solution. Thanks!

Comment: One could also use a `GenericForeignKey` with contenttypes. See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations-1)